# Sudden Spike in mobile app crawl errors - Search console

Tags: seo, google-search-console, googlebot, crawl-errors

We are seeing something weird in our mobile app crawl dashboard on the search console.

Up until 3rd Feb, we had only 3 crawl errors but suddenly that number is now 107k and it went up between 3rd and 8th feb and has continued to go up, and now crawling has stopped completely. We have a website that is linked to the app in the play store console (app indexing).

The most common error seems to be that google is doing "Google Automated mapping" and getting a Intent URI not supported error.

Eg:

> Intent URI not supported We couldn’t open the app page you selected.
>   Make sure your app manifest supports HTTP URLs and that they’re
>   formatted correctly in your sitemap.
>
> Source:   Google automated mapping
>
> App URI:    android-app://com.example.example.html
>
> Web URL:   https://www.example.com/example. (sample data)

[image]

Is there a setting to stop this?

Same question was raised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485918/gsc-intent-uri-not-supported-yes-i-didnt-created-the-intent-for-that-url) on Stackoverflow and I raised a bounty there.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about [operating websites](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so this is better suited for Stack Overflow where you already had posted it. In the future, please do not [cross-post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites since that spreads answers out among them.

Comment: Thanks, I moved it because to me it didn't feel like it was meant for SO (its not really a programming question) but an SEO question linked to a working website (and a linked mobile app) that I run and I can see its a generic question given that this is happening to multiple people. I moved it here, since I didnt raise the original question but instead raised a bounty there. I'll leave this to be on hold for now while I wait for someone to answer on SO. I'll reask/reword it if I dont get answers there

Comment: OK, if you don't get any answers there, try to reword it so it's more focused on the website, and add a comment here with '@dan' in it and I'll reopen it.